# foreach only working for last element in repeating

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to make an image zoomer thing. It was for an image list. to get every image I did this

and the html code

```js
var image = document.querySelectorAll('.card-img-top-mop');
image.forEach((cimg) => {
  var img = cimg.firstChild.nextSibling;
  var hover = cimg.parentElement;
  console.log(hover)
  hover.onmousemove = (e) => {
    img.style.transform = 'scale(1.5)';
  }
  hover.onmouseout = () => {
    img.style.transform = 'scale(1.0)';
  }

})
```

```css
.card-img-top-mop {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner {
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
}

.card-img-top-mop img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.who {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.who:hover {
  color: rgb(83, 80, 80);
}

.who:active {
  color: rgb(117, 106, 106);
}

.who:focus {
  color: rgb(92, 82, 82);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active card-img-top-mop">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576669801343-117bb4054118?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTB8fHNhbXBsZXxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100 huo" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item card-img-top-mop">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583912267670-6575ad472688?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTR8fHNhbXBsZXxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100 huo" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item card-img-top-mop">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576670159375-8beb7c963ead?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTd8fHNhbXBsZXxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" class="d-block w-100 huo" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev who" style=" background-color: transparent; outline: none; border: none;" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <i class="fad fa-angle-left" ></i>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next who" style=" background-color: transparent; outline: none; border: none;" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
              <i class="fad fa-angle-right"></i>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
</div>
```

Here The image (img variable) as the child of cimg variable. When I gave

```
cimg.onmouseover = (e) => {
......
}
```

, It Worked. But I gave the parent of cimg (hover variable) .Like The Code Above and this

```
hover.onmousemove = (e) => {
   ...
}
```

. It didn't work. Then It only does with the last child of cimg. It doesn't give the other child of time as output.
I didn't find the correct answer or didn't understand it. *Please teach me the answer. **Thank You Very Much***.
sorry if difficult to understand (actually this is my first post)

Comment: Can you add to your question more detail about what part of your solution are you haveing trouble with?

Comment: Some html code would be useful – please add it to your question...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i misunderstand, but why you can't use css directly for the efect? Something like:

```
.card-img-top-mop:hover img{
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

[Like in this pen](https://codepen.io/juancruzsaldana/pen/XWpMMJe)

on the other hand yo must include jquery in order to make bootstrap carousel feature work. The cdn for that is:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But If I hover the arrows then it will again be scaled 100%. and I also want to get the mouse-movement because by the movement I can make the image zoomer

Comment: oh, ok in this case i suggest add event listener to container div, something like
   `var image = document.querySelectorAll('.card-img-top-mop');
image.forEach((cimg) => {
  var img = cimg.firstChild.nextSibling;
  var hover = cimg.parentElement;
  hover.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
    img.style.transform = 'scale(1.5)';
  }); 
  hover.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    img.style.transform = 'scale(1.0)';
  }); 
})`

[example](https://codepen.io/juancruzsaldana/pen/XWpMMJe)

Comment: I have done it but if I want the parent of the hover variable then the problem comes.

`var hover = cimg.parentElement;
hover.parentElement.onmousemove = (e) => { 
.......
}`